# Need to give a non-privileged user permission to execute apachectl script

Tags: sudo, apache-httpd

I want that a regular user to be able to execute apachectl in the system. And that would be the only thing that they can do outside of it normal permissions. What I did is to add this line at the bottom of the sudoers file:

```
sampleuser ALL=(root)      NOEXEC:/usr/sbin/apachectl
```

So, as the user sampleuser, I executed `apachectl` command, and I get this error:

```
$ sudo apachectl stop 
[sudo] password for sampleuser: 
/usr/sbin/apachectl: line 105: /usr/sbin/httpd: Permission denied
```

Now it seems like the permission is with the /usr/sbin/httpd command since `apachectl` script calls that executable file. So I added another line to the sudoers file:

```
sampleuser ALL=(root)      NOEXEC:/usr/sbin/httpd
```

Now I executed the same command and I get the same error:

```
sudo apachectl start
[sudo] password for sampleuser: 
/usr/sbin/apachectl: line 105: /usr/sbin/httpd: Permission denied
```

My question now, is that if there's a fix for this without having to edit the apachectl script file or another method that probably is easier than what I'm trying to do.

Thank you.

Comment: If I was to hazard a guess, it’s be that selinux doesn’t like a domain transition in there.

Comment: @JeffSchaller But selinux is not active. ```getenforce 
Disabled```

Comment: Does `ls -l /usr/sbin/httpd ` show root ownership and execute bits?

Comment: @JeffSchaller Yes  `-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 545024 Sep 24  2017 /usr/sbin/httpd*`

Answer (score 0):

Apachectl does not know that it needs to use sudo to execute httpd

Try something like this:

```
APACHE_HTTPD='sudo -E /usr/sbin/httpd' sudo -E /usr/sbin/apachectl start

-E, --preserve-env
             Indicates to the security policy that the user wishes to reserve their
             existing environment variables.  The security policy may eturn an error
             if the user does not have permission to preserve the environment.
```

So you will force apache2ctl to use a different command to call httpd...

Comment: I get this error: `sudo: sorry, you are not allowed to set the following environment variables: APACHE_HTTPD`

Comment: `Apachectl stop` is already running under sudo though...

Comment: Yes, but it is just a script, when the script tries to call the subprocess httpd, the sudo will block it? I am not sure...

Comment: Is it perhaps possible to give the user access to that env variable?

Comment: `Amazon Linux AMI release 2017.09` I think that's based on fedora `ID_LIKE="rhel fedora"`

Comment: Hummmm I edited the answer please try again with this new format. The old format are not working here too. Maybe you also needs configure sudo to accept the use of environment variables...

Comment: Hello?  Are you there?

Comment: @LucianoAndressMartini I pasted your command and I get a similar error: `sudo: sorry, you are not allowed to preserve the environment`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/76931/discussion-between-vato-and-luciano-andress-martini).

Comment: Add a SETENV parameter for the command for your user on sudoers